# When 2 divs are moving on the screen, top div is not visible

Tags: javascript, css, html

We need to implement a screen saver which should have 3 images.

- The bottom image should be fixed.
- Middle image will be moving.
- Top image will be moving at relatively higher speed.

We created 3 divs to handle the images as below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Moving Screen Saver</title>
        <style>
            html, body {
                position: relative;
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
            }

            #bgimg {
                background-image: url("background/moon_bg.png");
                position: absolute;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-size: cover;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }

            .animator {
                width: 100vw;
                height: 100vh;
            }

            #poster {
                background-image: url("posters/gladiator.png");
                position: absolute;
                background-position:right 20px bottom 20px;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                background-color: transparent;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="bgimg"></div>
        <div class="animator"></div>
        <div id="poster"></div>
        <script>
            var poster = document.getElementById('poster');
            var animate;

            function moveRight()
            {
                poster.style.left = poster.style.left || 0;
                poster.style.left = parseInt(poster.style.left) - 10 + 'px';
                requestAnimationFrame(moveRight);
            }

            moveRight();

            function rollAnimate(element, url) {
                if(!element instanceof HTMLElement)
                    return;
                var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                var img = new Image();
                var x = 0;
                var pattern;
                var framesPerSec = 10;

                img.onload = startDrawing;
                img.onerror = console.error;
                img.src = url;
                canvas.style.cssText = 'position:absolute;'

                function startDrawing() {
                    element.insertBefore(canvas, element.firstChild);
                    pattern = ctx.createPattern(img, 'repeat');
                    resize();
                    anim();
                    window.addEventListener('resize', resize, {passive: true});
                }

                function anim() {
                    x = (x - 1) % img.width;
                    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,x,(canvas.height) - (img.height));
                    ctx.fill();
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        requestAnimationFrame(anim);
                        }, 1000 / framesPerSec);
                }

                function resize(evt) {
                    canvas.width = element.offsetWidth;
                    canvas.height = element.offsetHeight;
                    ctx.fillStyle =  pattern;
                    ctx.rect(0, canvas.height - img.height, canvas.width, img.height);
                    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'copy';
                }
            }

            rollAnimate(document.querySelector('.animator'), 'buildings/mod_cropped.png');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

- lower image - bgimg
- middle image - animator
- top image - poster

We are able to see lower image which is fixed and middle image which is moving. But poster image is not visible. We are thinking that this is because when we are trying to paint middle image it is replacing top image. Can any one please help me to fix this issue.

Below is jsfiddle page

https://jsfiddle.net/n76epste/10/

Comment: @Gerard It's included

Comment: @kadina can you provide a JSFiddle

Comment: @SethMcClaine: i edited to include JSFiddle page.

Comment: In your jsFiddle `.poster{ background-image: url(""); }` I assume this is filled in in your actual code since your example here use "posters/gladiator.png"?

Comment: right. the url was empty. And also I see that both images "gladiator" and "moon background" are the same images. You might want to use the right image.

Comment: @SethMcClaine: Sorry. I updated the correct link. Yes. I used correctly in the code.

Comment: @SeshaKiran: I am using the right image in the code. But when I copy pasted in jsfiddle, I missed urls. Now I updated correctly. Could you please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of Z-index. I changed z-index of poster dev tp the highest to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So when I look, you are actually getting all 3 images. Your issue is the `poster` moves off screen super fast and never returns.

- `bgimg` is static and covered by animator (you can see this by deleting animator)
- `animator` is animated and repeating and cover bgimage
- `poster` is given an ever updating `style="left: -***px"` where * is an increasing number. (You can see this for a split second when loading the page if you hide `bgimg` and `animator` with css)

Comment: Yes. I want to move the poster image to move to the left completely.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. If you move it off the screen it's not visible...

Comment: Main thing is when one poster moves to left completely, we need to display different poster. User will be displayed one movie poster which is moving to left and once it moves to left completely, another movie poster will be displayed. So initially we thought of checking with one poster.

Comment: ahhh... so when your VALUE of `style=left:VALUEpx` is greater than the width of the poster, update the poster background-image to a new poster and reset the VALUE to the initial value.  Does that make sense?

Comment: That is true to change to new poster. But can you please help me what changes I need to do to make it visible that poster is moving to the left as right now we are unable to see the poster moving to the left. Is it because it is moving too fast?

Comment: Yes, super fast!

Comment: I changed the code to display the poster as I am doing to display the middle image. So now both should be moving at the same speed. But still I am unable to see the poster.

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/n76epste/25/ I have hidden the other two images